# Убрать крестик в img

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, css3

Если нет картинки то отображается крестик. Так в EDGE происодит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как убрать этот крестик?

Comment: Можно не добавлять картинку в dom, если она не загружена.

Comment: https://bitsofco.de/styling-broken-images/

Comment: @AlexeyTen забавно, что в разделе совместимости в статье ИЕ и едж вообще не упомянуты )

Comment: это в смысле есть тег `img` а а `href` пустой то тогда отображается крестик ?

Comment: @teran ну в 2016 Edge ещё и в проекте не было. В общем надо проверять

Comment: @AlexeyTen чего вдруг не было? в 15м вышел

Comment: о! Он такой старый =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый нормальный вариант это картинка-плейсхолдер, как то реализовано во всех нормальных cms. Иначе страница будет ломаться во всех случаях, кроме тех, когда тегу img заданы width и height (а если `onerror="this.style.display='none'"` то будет ломаться всё равно). И уж точно делать подобные манипуляции желательно ещё на сервере.

Answer (score 0):

Применить:

```html
<img src="Error.src" onerror="this.style.display='none'"/>
```